Monitor and shutdown Gazebo and ROS multiple parallel simulations
I need to run multiple Gazebo (Fortress) and ROS 2 simulation in parallel. To do this I will launch the simulation from a Python script, each simulation will have its own ROS_DOMAIN_ID value and IGN_PARTITION value.
I already have a pipeline that can launch multiple simulation but I'm struggling in finding a way to communicate to the Python script if the simulation is valid or not (I tried with ros2 param but I cannot read a parameter value without creating a Node), and how to kill the simulation if it's invalid and restart it properly.
Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks!
